# Write a program to display even numbers from 1 to 100 seperated by comma

Tags: java

Write a program to display even numbers from 1 to 100 seperated by
comma

```
public class Evennumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=1;
        
        while(i<=100)
        {
        
            if(i%2==0)
                System.out.print( i+" ,");
            
            i++;
        }

    }
}
```

The Out put of the program is placed below :

> 2 ,4 ,6 ,8 ,10 ,12 ,14 ,16 ,18 ,20 ,22 ,24 ,26 ,28 ,30 ,32 ,34 ,36 ,38
> ,40 ,42 ,44 ,46 ,48 ,50 ,52 ,54 ,56 ,58 ,60 ,62 ,64 ,66 ,68 ,70 ,72
> ,74 ,76 ,78 ,80 ,82 ,84 ,86 ,88 ,90 ,92 ,94 ,96 ,98 ,100 ,

/** I want to remove comma after 100 **/

Comment: Then you should print `","` only if `i != 100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this. Print the first number and then print the rest `preceded` by a comma.

```
String comma = "";
for(int i = 2; i <= 100; i+= 2) {
   System.out.print(comma + i);
   comma = ", ";
}
```

prints

```
2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 
44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80, 82, 
84, 86, 88, 90, 92, 94, 96, 98, 100
```

Comment: public class Evennumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=1;
        
        while(i<=100)
        {
        
            if(i%2==0)
             if(i==100) {
              System.out.print( i);
             }
             else
                System.out.print( i+", ");
            
            i++;
        }

    }
}